# Returning a confirmation dialog before submitting form not working

Tags: javascript, php, forms, form-submit, confirm

I'm trying to get the website to return a confirmation dialog before submitting the form, but it's not working for some reason. It returned the confirmation dialog, but after clicking 'yes', it does not submit the form. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

echo "
<form action = 'delete.php' method = 'POST'>
<label id = 'delete' onclick = \"return confirm('Are you sure?');this.form.submit()\"> delete </label>
</form>
";

?>
```

**Note:**

Instead of using input:submit, I would rather use the label onclick() along with the confirmation dialog. Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onclick` handler in your code just returns `confirm` dialog result and ignores the rest part of code (`this.form.submit()`);
I would recommend to use outer function in such case:

```
<?php

echo "
<form action = 'delete.php' method = 'POST'>
<label id = 'delete' onclick = \"confirmSubmit(this);\"> delete </label>
</form>
";

?>
```

js code:

```
function confirmSubmit(e){
    var need_submit = confirm('Are you sure?');
    if (need_submit) e.form.submit();
}
```